# aru Kanji confusion

Tags: kanji, kanji-choice, old-japanese, jōyō-kanji

In the sentence:

> 今日は宿題があります。

would I use

在る or 有る?

(I know that today it's almost always written in Kana)
Thanks in advance :)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

有る is for possession; 在る is for existence.  Though there can be some overlap.  And 或る (even though you didn't ask) is actually an adjective for "a particular/certain", like in `ある日に...`.

So in this case, I'm mostly certain it would be 有る since you "have" homework.

Here are some words that might help remember the difference:

### 有

- 所有　→　one's possessions; ownership
- 有罪　→　guilty; "having" guilt
- 共有　→　sharing; joint ownership
- 有料　→　something that costs money (as opposed to free 無料); "having" a cost
- 有力　→　strong; influential; "having" power

### 在

- 所在　→　whereabouts
- 存在　→　existence
- 在日　→　living/staying in Japan (particularly used for foreigners)
- 現在　→　the present (time)
- 在庫　→　inventory (merchandise)

Comment: I see, I didn't mention 或る since it wasn't logical in this example. I allready knew the difference in general, but wasn't getting it in this sentence, since it could mean: "Homework exist for me" instead of "I have homework" but obviously you can't directly translate like that.
Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I guess you have already acknowledged though, [在日{ざいにち}](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%9C%A8%E6%97%A5-508243) is normally used for foreigners' living in Japan especially Korean.

Comment: @kimiTanaka:  Yes, I know this, but it's not obvious to anyone reading my answer.  I'll add it.

Answer (score 5):

Just a little bit of background on this:

As you mentioned, it is generally written as `ある` these days. In the past, there was a clearer differentiation based on grammatical properties, i.e. that `有る` was used in a transitive sense like `Xを所有する` ('to possess X'), whereas `在る` was used in an intransitive sense like `Xが存在する` ('X exists'). However, that distinction seems to have become blurred somewhat since the Hiragana `ある` became dominant.

Nonetheless, you can make an argument that if you were to use kanji to represent `ある`, you could base your choice on those older usages mentioned above. In the case of your specific example, there is an implied subject to the sentence (私は is omitted but clearly understood) and an object to the sentence (宿題). This would mean that the transitive sense of 所有する would be a more appropriate choice.

**Therefore the correct choice would be `有る`** - assuming that you are communicating the meaning 'I' the subject of the sentence, have homework today.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!